# Como substituir variáveis com valores NEGATIVOS por seu VALOR ABSOLUTO dentro de um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, matemática, data.frame

Antes de mais nada, o que é um Valor Absoluto?

Podemos dizer que o Valor Absoluto ou o Módulo é o mesmo que a distância de um número real ao número zero, pois o módulo de um número real surgiu da necessidade de medir a distância de um número negativo ao zero.
Ao medirmos a distância de um número negativo qualquer ao zero, percebe-se que a distância fica negativa e como não é usual dizer que uma distância ou comprimento é negativo foi criado o módulo de número real que torna o valor positivo ou nulo.

Assim, podemos dizer que o módulo de um número real irá seguir duas condições:

• O módulo ou valor absoluto de um número real é o próprio número, se ele for positivo.

• O módulo ou valor absoluto de um número real será o seu simétrico, se ele for negativo.

O Valor Absoluto é representado por barras paralelas e é calculado da seguinte maneira. Exemplo:

```
x = |-5| + |-7|

x = √(-5²) + √(-7²)

x = √25 + √49

x = 5 + 7

x = 12
```

Agora que sabemos o que é e como calcular o Valor Absoluto, voltemos ao problema aplicado no R.

Digamos que tenho um data.frame 6x5, exemplo:

```
print(Dados)

Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3  -1   2   4
L2     1  -2   1  -5   1
L3    -1  -1   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5  -7   9
```

Mas preciso substituir os valores Negativos do data.frame pelo Valor Absoluto, exemplo:

```
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3   1   2   4
L2     1   2   1   5   1
L3     1   1   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5   7   9
```

Como posso fazer para substituir as variáveis com valores NEGATIVOS pelo VALOR ABSOLUTO dentro do meu data.frame?

Dados:

```
Dados <- read.table(text = "
Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3  -1   2   4
L2     1  -2   1  -5   1
L3    -1  -1   2   3   4
L4     2   4   5  -7   9
", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando a função `abs`:

```
library(dplyr)

Dados %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric, abs)
##   Linha A B C D E
## 1    L1 4 3 1 2 4
## 2    L2 1 2 1 5 1
## 3    L3 1 1 2 3 4
## 4    L4 2 4 5 7 9
```

Comment: Você foi mais rápido que eu. Vou apagar a minha,  hahaha. Melhor solução é essa mesmo.

Comment: Hahaha acontece : )

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Marcus Nunes e neves. Vou testar.

Answer (score 3):

Use a função `abs` (absolute value). Como o módulo (valor absoluto) só pode ser calculado sobre números, a solução mais coerente é analisar pelas classes dos vetores presentes em `Dados`.

Supondo que queira analisar vetores de números inteiros (que é o seu caso), você pode utilizar a função `rapply`, do `R base`, a qual dispensa uso de pacotes adicionais:

```
rapply(object = Dados, classes = 'integer', how = 'replace', f = abs)

  Linha A B C D E
1    L1 4 3 1 2 4
2    L2 1 2 1 5 1
3    L3 1 1 2 3 4
4    L4 2 4 5 7 9
```

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a função `abs(Dados)`

[Referência](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/SparkR/versions/2.1.2/topics/abs)

[Referência no StackOverflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22306175/change-negative-values-in-dataframe-column-to-absolute-value)

Comment: Isso não dá certo por conta de `Dados` possuir um fator.